# Development of a problem of the course on ODE MIT 18.03

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

From the course MIT 18.03 about ODE, there is that following problem [18.03SC practice problem 2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/geometric-methods/MIT18_03SCF11_rec_02s2_sol.pdf)
For the ODE:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = x-2y
$$
One of the integral curves seems to be a straight line. What straight line is it? (i.e., for what $m$ and $b$ is $y = mx + b$ a solution?)

**answer**:

If $y = mx + b$ is a solution, then
$$
m = \frac{dy}{dx} = x-2y = x-2(mx+b)
$$
or, rearranging terms,
$$
m = (1 − 2m)x − 2b\tag{1}
$$
Two polynomials in x can only be the same for all x (over the reals) if they have the same coefficients. Equate coefficients of the powers of x to get two equations in two unknowns that must be satisfied simultaneously.
$$
\begin{cases}
m&=-2b\\
0&=1-2m\tag{2}
\end{cases}
$$

**How do we develop step by step to come to (2) from (1)**:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although what is stated should be sufficient, you can look at it like this:

The equation must hold for $x=0$, so $$m=-2b$$ Substituting for $b$ gives $$(1-2m)x =0 $$ This equation must hold for $x=1$, so $$1-2m=0$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Tavish. One last question: what does the sentence "Two polynomials in $x$ can only the same for all $x$ (over the reals) if they have the same coefficients". What are the two polynomials here?

Comment: @ecjb The two polynomials are taken to be $m$ and $(1-2m)x-2b$, and they have compared coefficients.